# Does not generate @XMLRootElement jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

This is my .xsd file

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Person" type="PersonType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="PersonType">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Address" type="AddressType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="AddressType">

        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

using this XSD file I Generated this class :

```
package demo5;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PersonType", propOrder = {
  "name",
  "address"
})
public class PersonType {

@XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
protected String name;
@XmlElement(name = "Address", required = true)
protected List<AddressType> address;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}
public List<AddressType> getAddress() {
    if (address == null) {
        address = new ArrayList<AddressType>();
    }
    return this.address;
}

}
```

but XSD file does not generates the @XMLRootElement in the java file. any one can give a solution for this. I know  can generate the root element but this does not work.

Answer (score 6):

For global elements corresponding to named complex types an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on the `ObjectFactory` class will be generated instead of an `@XmlRootElement` annotation on the class.  This is because there may be more than one global element corresponding to the same named complex type.  This use case could not be met by using `@XmlRootElement`.

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="Person")
    public JAXBElement<PersonType> createPerson(PersonType personType) {
        return new JAXBElement<PersonType>(new QName("Person"), PersonType.class, personType);
    }

}
```

**Creating the `JAXBContext`**

When creating a `JAXBContext` based on a model generated from an XML Schema it should be done on the package name of the generated model.  This is so the metadata in the `ObjectFactory` class gets processed.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("demo5");
```

Or the generated `ObjectFactory` class:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(demo5.ObjectFactory.class);
```

**Unmarshalling the Class**

When you unmarshal a class in which the root element corresponds to an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation you will get an instance of `JAXBElement` back.

```
JAXBElement<PersonType> je = (JAXBElement<PersonType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
PersonType pt = je.getValue();
```

If you want to guard against a `JAXBElement` being returned you can always use the `JAXBIntrospector` on the result of the unmarshal operation:

```
PersonType pt = (PersonType) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml));
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Answer (score 2):

The `@XMLRootElement` will only be generated for anonymous types of top elements, not top-level types.

Comment: The @XMLRootElement is generated ONLY for top-level types.

Comment: @JeffWalker no, `@XMLRootElement` will only be be generated for anonymous types (of top elements)